# GeoPackage - Drag & Drop vs adding layers from connection

Tags: qgis-3, geopackage

I am using QGIS 3.12.3, and created a GeoPackage through the layer panel by dragging and dropping both vector data (a polygon, a point and a tabular layer) and a raster underneath it. I even applied styling to it, which created an additional .qml file. Yet, I was assuming that styling would also be stored within the gpkg file.

When I tried to drag & drop the GeoPackage directly into QGIS, only raster file appears, yet if I add a connection then all the files appear correctly. Should I be storing only vector data in a GeoPackage or why drag&drop differs from browsing the files through a GeoPackage connection?

Comment: Yes. But, presumably it also effects the original file?

Comment: Also, when I create the Geoapackage by only including the vector and tabular data, and edit the "Attributes Form" of the tabular data - it does not load the saved properties (under the "Value Map" relation) when I open the Geopackage the next time.

Comment: It is not clear how to save styles for each layer in a GeoPackage. Specifically, each time a style is saved to a local database, the existing styles in the qml file (QGIS Layer Settings) are overridden.